# Reactive Mongo Repository Logging

Tags: spring-boot, logging

With Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7, I want to log the queries generated by `ReactiveMongoRepository`. I have tried the following configs,

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG
org.springframework.data.document.mongodb: DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb: DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb: DEBUG
```

but still, the queries are not logged. Any more configuration needed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use reactiveMongoTemplate configuration

logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate=DEBUG